# Operations on two fairly large Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two .csv files that I need to do some operations on. In one file (file1.csv) there are over 800k positions (in 2D cartesian frame). In second file (poi.csv) I have around 7k points of interest (also in 2D cartesian frame). I want to find closest point of interest of every position from file1. My current approach is to iterate over every position from file1, next iterate over every position from poi and finding minimum, but it takes really long time. Is there any way to speed this up in Python?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: this is actually quite a hard problem! I think the best option might be some kind of tree structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`scipy.spatial.KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree).

Consider two dataframes `df_1` and `df_2`:

```
    Name1  x1  y1
0  Point1   0   0
1  Point2  10  10
2  Point3  11  10
3  Point4   5   5

  Name2  x2  y2
0    p1  11  11
1    p2   1   1
2    p3   9   5
```

Then you can do:

```py
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

tree = KDTree(df_1[["x1", "y1"]])

nearest_dist, nearest_ind = tree.query(df_2[["x2", "y2"]], k=1)
print(nearest_dist)
print(nearest_ind)
```

Prints:

```
[1.         1.41421356 4.        ]
[2 0 3]
```

---

Combining it to output dataframe:

```py
print(pd.concat([df_2, df_1.loc[nearest_ind].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1))
```

Prints:

```
  Name2  x2  y2   Name1  x1  y1
0    p1  11  11  Point3  11  10
1    p2   1   1  Point1   0   0
2    p3   9   5  Point4   5   5
```